# Ensuring user input is not a string

Tags: c#

I am having trouble checking if the user input is a whole/real number and is within range 12-36. I can't seem to get the program to output an error message if the input is not a number. I need the program to check if the input is a number using Tryparse, but if it is not an error message occurs. The error message doesen't work, instead the program crashes when I try to run it.

```
Console.Write("Please enter the diameter of your pizza: "); // get user to input pizzaDiameter

        Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pizzaDiameter); // read the users keyboard
        //and convert input to real number to hold as the pizzaDiameter variable


        /**********************************************************************************
          *                                                                               *
          *                         PROCESSING                                            *
          *                                                                               *
          * *******************************************************************************/

        while (pizzaDiameter != QUIT_PROGRAM && needInput) // Begin while loop
        {



            // determine if diameter is within 12 to 36
            // if does not meet requirements show error message and have user enter in new diameter
            //if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pizzaDiameter))
            //{
                //Console.WriteLine("\nENTRY ERROR\n\nPizza diameter must be a whole or real number.\n\nPlease try again");
            //}
            //else
            //{
                //needInput = false;
            //}
                if (pizzaDiameter < MINIMUM_DIAMETER || pizzaDiameter > MAXIMUM_DIAMETER)
                {
                    //error message detailing why the program failed to calculate
                    Console.WriteLine("\nENTRY RANGE ERROR\n\nPizza must have a diameter in the range of 12” to 36” inclusive!\n\nPlease try again");
                }
                else
                {    //program is satisfied with the inputted amount and will now move on to the range checking
                    needInput = false;



                    //Determines the number of slices based on user inputted diameter
                    if (pizzaDiameter <= DIAMETER_SMALL)//checks if pizzaDiameter is <=small
                    {
                        pizzaSlices = (SLICES_MINIMUM);//sets pizzaSlices to the minimum of 8
                    }
                    else if (pizzaDiameter <= DIAMETER_MEDIUM)//diameter range for <24
                    {
                        pizzaSlices = (SLICES_MEDIUM);// sets number of slices to 12
                    }
                    else if (pizzaDiameter <= DIAMETER_LARGE)//diameter range for <30
                    {
                        pizzaSlices = (SLICES_HIGH);// sets number of slices to 16
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pizzaSlices = (SLICES_MAXIMUM);//sets maximum slices because diameter is >30
                    }
```

Comment: `if(Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pizzaDiameter)) { Console.WriteLine("ok"); } else { Console.WriteLine("error!"); }`

Comment: If the program "crashes" then that means an exception is being thrown and not being handled.  Catch exceptions so you can examine them and handle them.

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: The code doesn't compile. It is a typo? There is an else if just after the test on the diameters that is incorrect

Comment: I just removed the error msg for when input fails to be converted, it runs fine. Now i need to figure out how to check and if conversion fails to give the user a msg

Comment: TryParse methods returns FALSE when they fail to convert the string to the requested numeric value. You give the error message when TryParse returns true.

Comment: alright so how do I change it to teturn the message when it is false. i'm new to c#

Comment: Move the two lines that are out of the while loop inside it and `if(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Pizzadiameter)) ....error message else continue with min/max checks` Now you have truncated the previous code, but there is a block at the end of the while loop that reask the input. You could remove all of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are logical errors and trivial errors in your code.

Start with moving the first two lines inside the while loop and remove the needInput variable

```
// Just to enter the loop the first time....
double pizzaDiameter = 1.0d;
const double QUIT_PROGRAM = 0.0d;

while (pizzaDiameter != QUIT_PROGRAM) 
{
     Console.Write("Please enter the diameter of your pizza: (0 to exit) "); 

     // Add the NOT operator in front of the TryParse call
     if(!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pizzaDiameter))
     {
        ... false returned by TryParse
        ... error message....
     }
     else if( .... check for diameter min/max .....)
     {
        ... diameter not valid error message
     }
     else
     {
        .... start calculus....
     }
     // end while here... 
     // if input is incorrect the loop restart until diameter = 0
     // So, no need to ask again the pizza diameter in this point
 }
```